# Post knockout observable array as object property asp.net mvc

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc, knockout.js

I'm trying to post an ko.observable array as part of of an object, all that data reaches the server ok except for the array which is not null but has a count of zero.

**This is on the client side**

```
    function submitAsync() {
    var viewModel = constructModel();

    setTimeout(function () {
        $.ajax({
            url: '/Article/Index',
            type: 'POST',
            data: JSON.stringify({ viewModel: viewModel }),
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        })
    },2000);
    console.log(viewModel);
}

function constructModel(){
    var articleViewModel = {};
    articleViewModel.Authors = ko.toJSON(appViewModel.authors);

    articleViewModel.ArticleData = {};
    articleViewModel.ArticleData.Title = $("#ArticleData_Title").text();
    articleViewModel.ArticleData.CorespondingAuthor = $("#ArticleData_CorespondingAuthor").text();
    articleViewModel.ArticleData.Keywords = $("#ArticleData_Keywords").text();

    articleViewModel.ArticleContent = {};
    articleViewModel.ArticleContent.Abstract = $("#ArticleContent_Abstract").text();
    articleViewModel.ArticleContent.FullText = ArticleContent();

    return articleViewModel;
}
```

**My viewModel**

```
public class ArticleViewModel
{
    public ArticleData ArticleData { get; set; }
    public ArticleContent ArticleContent { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Author> Authors { get; set; }
}
```

**My controller action** viewModel.Authors is not null but has a count of 0

```
[HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Index(ArticleViewModel viewModel)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                mergeViewModelToCurrentArticle(viewModel);
                _documentPath = GenerateDocument(_currentArticle);
                return RedirectToAction("Success");
            }
            return View();
        }
```

**The ko array outputed from javascript**

```
Authors: "[{"id":1,"firstName":"User first name","lastName":"user last name","email":"user@gmail.com","phone":"xxxxx","address":"Dunarii Nr.3","fullName":"user full name"}]"
```

Comment: How is one `Author` looks like in C#? You can also try with data: `JSON.stringify(viewModel),`

Comment: The casing of the property names should match. In JS you have `firstName` but in C# `FirstName`...

Comment: without JSON.stringify i get Invalid JSON primitive: Authors.

Comment: i've updated it now the data i post looks like `Authors: "[{"Id":1,"FirstName":"First Name","LastName":"LastName","Email":"email@gmail.com","Phone":"0751000000","Address":"Dunarii Nr.3","fullName":"First Name LastName"}]"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to Darin i managed to figure it out apparently the solution was to replace

```
articleViewModel.Authors = ko.toJSON(appViewModel.authors);
```

with

```
articleViewModel.Authors = $.parseJSON(ko.toJSON(appViewModel.authors))
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply replace

```
articleViewModel.Authors = ko.toJSON(appViewModel.authors);
```

with:

```
articleViewModel.Authors = appViewModel.authors;
```

You are double JSON encoding the Authors array which is not necessary.

Comment: Thought about that, and tried it already but if i do that Authors now becomes null, instead of having a count of 0

Comment: Try removing the `implicit operator` from your `Author` model.

Comment: That didn't work either and is used to work when i posted just the authors, even with the implicit operator

Comment: That's weird. Could you please show the exact JSON that gets sent to the server during the AJAX request? I suspect that there might be some discrepancy between your model and the JSON string.

Comment: Don't really think so because as i said it worked when i was just posting the authors, but i'm really new at this. Here's the JSON

Comment: Could you please post the exact JSON as string? Also what you have shown in your questoion is wrong because you have double quotes around the `Authors` property meaning that it is double JSON encoded. That's why it is not working. The JSON that you should send to the server should look like this: `{"articleData": {},"articleContent": {},"authors": [{"id":1,"firstName":"User first name","lastName":"user last name","email":"user@gmail.com","phone":"xxxxx","address":"Dunarii Nr.3","fullName":"user full name"}]}`.

Comment: This is with you're suggestion without using ko.toJSON `{"ArticleData":{"Title":"Paper title","CorespondingAuthor":"","Keywords":""},"ArticleContent":{"Abstract":"Abstract text","FullText":""}} ` as you can is the i don't have anything for authors that's why it null. With ko.toJSON i get `{"Authors":"[{\"Id\":1,\"FirstName\":\"First Name\",\"LastName\":\"LastName\",\"Email\":\"email@gmail.com\",\"Phone\":\"0751000000\",\"Address\":\"Dunarii Nr.3\",\"fullName\":\"First Name LastName\"}]"`. I've erased some from the last to large for comments

Comment: Yes, you don't have anything, so I don't understand what do you expect to get back on your server, other than null. Your JSON just must contain the `Authors` array if you want to get it on the server. So I guess that the problem is with your `appViewModel.authors` variable which is empty at the moment you are calling it.

Comment: apparent the solution was to replace `articleViewModel.Authors = ko.toJSON(appViewModel.authors);` with `articleViewModel.Authors = $.parseJSON(ko.toJSON(appViewModel.authors));` can u add this to you're answer so i can mark it as the correct oen